# Persistent Background Task in iOS 2024

Tags: ios, flutter, background-process, persistent, background-task

I need to run a persistent background task, which speaks if a new message comes in to inform the user. Till now i couldn't find any "legal" way to make that happen. Apple has pretty strict guidelines on that.

I am using flutter with the package flutter background service. It worked perfectly for android with an ongoing foreground process, but due to ios restrictions my process is killed after a short time in the background.

If it's necessary i can also implement something natively in ios.

A friend recommended me this: [Continuously run an IOS app in the background even after sleep or reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054669/continuously-run-an-ios-app-in-the-background-even-after-sleep-or-reboot/28284374#28284374)
Anyone experience if this solution still works and passes the review?

Push notifications are not an option as they can't be read out loud. Also silent push could technically wake up my background process, but is also limited, so that's not an option either.

Looking forward for any answer, i also thought of contacting apple, i have read that special tasks can be sometimes allowed. (audio or timer, voip for example can be ongoing processes)

Comment: The rules and possibilities are perfectly clear: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes Background fetch and remote notification seem closest to your use case, but you will _never_ achieve the identical functionality as on Android.